# Stored procedure to insert record and for each run update statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I would like to have a stored procedure which inserts rows into a table (retrieved from a select query from another table) and for each newly inserted row gets its identity and updates the original table with the identity

Pseudo code-

```
records = select id,city,state,country from USER where name=@name

for each record in records  // for each rows selected
   insert into LOCATION(city,state,country) values(@record.city,@record.state,@record.country); //inserts a value into LOCATION table
   @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); // gets the identity of the newly inserted row
   update USER set LocationId=@id where Id=@record.id //updates the new id back to old table's column
end
```

This is a data migration task, where we want to segregate the LOCATION from USER table

Thanks in advance for your time and effort for this thread.

Comment: How do you identify the original column in the source table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @InsertedValues TABLE (ID INT, City VARCHAR(50), State VARCHAR(50), Country VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO dbo.Location(City, State, Country)
  OUTPUT Inserted.ID, Inserted.City, Inserted.State, Inserted.Country INTO @InsertedValues(ID, City, State, Country)
    SELECT City, State, Country
    FROM dbo.YourSourceTable
```

With this, you now have the inserted values - **including** the newly defined identity values - in your `@InsertedValues` table variable and you can now update the source table as you see fit.

```
UPDATE dbo.YourSourceTable
SET 
   Col1 = iv.Col1,
   Col2 = iv.Col2,  -- etc. - do whatever you nee to do here!
FROM @InsertedValues iv
WHERE  .........  -- here, you need some condition to link the inserted values to the original table
```

This doesn't require any cursor or any other messy RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) processing at all - everything is nicely set-based and as fast as it can possibly be.

Learn more about the `OUTPUT` clause at MSDN [SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) - you can use the `OUTPUT` clause on insert, update and even delete statements, too!

Comment: +1, for this particular case a cursor may not be needed indeed, because the `City, State, Country` set of columns seems a natural key and could be used in WHERE for matching the original table's rows. (And you could do without OUTPUT too.) In general, however, a cursor might be unavoidable. I mean cases where the original table's ID column is the only way to identify rows. It is not used in INSERT and, as a result, will be missing from the OUTPUT rowset. So, you won't be able to match the inserted rows against the original table. A MERGE would help, but, as we know, this is SQL Server 2005...